# How to mute .pyc file generation while running tests using nose2

Tags: python, python-2.7, nose

I'm using nose2 to run tests.
Every time, when I run tests python generates the bytecode. (.pyc file).

If we run the test directly using python command line with -B option will not generate .pyc files.

Is there any equivalent option in nose2? All I'm trying is how to stop .pyc being generated while I'm working on my tests.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you want it to write .pyc files?

Comment: I dont mind its generating .pyc files but having them along side the source code .py is cluterring

Comment: It might be easier to just have a "make clean" target in your Makefile to clean them up.

Answer (score 3):

The Python help shows the equivalent environment variable:

```
-B     : don't write .py[co] files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
```

Passing command-line options will be difficult, because nose2 isn't invoking Python as a command-line executable. Define the environment variable instead.

Comment: -B option is my question itself..do you know how to pass thru this argument from nose2 to python?

Comment: Define the PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE environment variable. It does the same thing.